# Google Maps appears to be turning off any other media

Tags: lg, google-maps-navigation

I'm using Gone Mad Music Player for music and Podcast Addict for podcasts and recently I've been having this problem where Google navigation will stop those apps from playing when it wants to give me a notification. When I restart the music/podcast app, Google navigation stops giving me notifications, forcing me to restart that thing.  I'm not sure how to fix it.  I do have navigation set to talk over anything that's playing.

Comment: *I do have navigation set to talk over anything that's playing*, where is that setting? I see only for playing over voice calls and this seems to be the designed behavior in that case